# File pointers led to core dump. Probably something stupid

Tags: c

Write the program myuniq.c that contains a function void process_file(FILE* f) that reads all input from the given file one line at the time while keeping two consecutive lines in memory, and prints each line to the standard output if it is not equal to the previously read line.

^^This is the assignment i'm working on. My code below is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void process_file(FILE* f);

int main()
{
  FILE *fil = fopen("text.txt","r");
  process_file(fil);

  return 0;
}

void process_file(FILE* f)
{
  FILE *fi = f;
  char *firstLine  = fgets(firstLine,  999, f);
  char *secondLine = fgets(secondLine, 999, f);

  while (feof(fi))
  {
    if (firstLine == secondLine)
    {
      puts(secondLine);
    }
    else
    {
      puts(firstLine);
      puts(secondLine);
    }
    firstLine++;
    secondLine++;
  }
}
```

It compiled fine...but on every run it says core dumped. I can't see where I went wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You don't check the return of `fopen` for another

Comment: `while (feof(fi))` is certainly an invention.

Comment: You only (attempt to) read the first two lines of the file. `firstLine++` doesn't read the next line; it increments the pointer so it points to the second *character* of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the return value of fopen, you don't allocate any memory for the strings into which you read, you don't continue reading input from the file, you don't correctly check for the end of input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MY_MAX_LINE 999

void process_file(FILE* f)
{
  char firstLine[MY_MAX_LINE + 1];
  char secondLine[MY_MAX_LINE + 1]; 

  while (1)
  {
    if (!fgets(firstLine, sizeof(firstLine), f))
      break;

    puts(firstLine);

    if (!fgets(secondLine, sizeof(secondLine), f))
      break;

    if (strncmp(firstLine, secondLine, sizeof(firstLine)))
      puts(secondLine);
  }

  if (!feof(f))
    perror("Problem reading from file"), exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "r");

  if (!f)
    perror("text.txt"), exit(1);

  process_file(f);
  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```